# Is it possible to use single conanfile.py both for creation and consuming a package?

Tags: conan

I'm studying the Conan package manager.

Its manuals and "getting started" tutorials show that `conanfile.py` is usually used to package some C++ code, and `conanfile.txt` - is for consuming that package.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69740163/704329) states that `conanfile.txt` is a simplification of `conanfile.py`, used by a consumer code.

I've also found [this page](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/mastering/conanfile_py.html), describing how to "translate" `conanfile.txt` into `conanfile.py`.

But file `conanfile.py`, created after that translation is anyway different from file `conanfile.py`, that was used to build a package.

My question: is it possible to merge them?
Is it possible to have a single `conanfile.py` that would either produce a package, or connect to a remote and download already produced one, depending on `conan` invocation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is totally  possible to use just one `conanfile.py` for both things, not only possible, but recommended.

The Conan 2.0 (beta) docs, already explain a bit better the advantages of using a `conanfile.py` also to just "consume" dependencies without really creating packages, see [this section in the 2.0 docs](https://docs.conan.io/en/2.0/tutorial/consuming_packages/the_flexibility_of_conanfile_py.html)

Just one detail, when doing `conan install` over a `conanfile.py`, you do not install that package created from that `conanfile.py` but its dependencies. If you want to install the package created from it, you need to `conan install pkg/version@user/channel` (in Conan 1.X) and `conan install --require=pkg/version` (in 2.0)